# navbar fixed top

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap

Como consigo deixar só o navbar como navbar-fixed no scroll e quando o cliente estiver no inicio do site, nao sobrepor o topo1, no momento ele esta sumindo quando coloco navbar-fixed e entra por baixo da pagina.

```html
<div class="row topo1" style="margin: 0px auto;">
    <div class="col-lg-12" >
        <div class="container">
            
     <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 phone pull-right" style="text-align:right; padding-top:2px;" >
      <ul>
      <a href="#">Parceiros&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>      
      
      <a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Veja seu Filho</a>
      </ul>
      </div>
          
        </div>
 </div>
</div>  


<div class="row" style="margin: 0px auto;">
    <div class="col-lg-12 topo" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
     
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;" >
                    <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo/logo2.png" alt="#" title="Logo Village" class="img-responsive" style="margin:0px auto; " ></a>
                </div>
                        
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right" style="padding:0px;" >
    
                        <nav class="navbar-right navbar-default" >
                            <div class="container-fluid "  >
                                   
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <button type="button"  class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                    <span class="sr-only" >Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Explique melhor o que quer, e se possivel, colocar um exemplo funcional

Comment: https://revolthemes.net/demo/mart/ entao, quando voce rola a pagina a primeira div que esta verde desaparece e o menu que é o navbar fica fixed top, eu gostaria de fazer o mesmo efeito, tem alguma ideia como?

Comment: Já tentou usar z-index para colocar o navbar por cima?

Comment: Tem como me dar um exemplo de como ficaria, assim consigo adaptar no meu codigo, ficaria super grato

Comment: Adicione o seguinte estilo ao seu **css:** `.topo1{z-index: 99;}`, veja se ele fica por cima.